# Unable to return both attributes using XPath in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, xpath

I have the following xml:

```
<td class="tableCell restrictionCell">
    <span class="restrictionEditLink"  rId="202">edit</span>
    &nbsp;<span class="restrictionDeleteLink"  rId="202">delete</span>
</td>
```

I'm attempting to extract the value of the rId attribute using the following XPath

```
//td/span/@rId
```

In JMeter it's returning 0 matches. If I test it in an online XPath tester, I'm getting the value as expected.

If I run:

```
//td/span/@class
```

JMeter returns the two class values as I expect.

Also attempted to use:

```
//td/span[@class="restrictionEditLink"]/@rId
```

Which also returns 0 results in JMeter, but the rId value in an online XPath tester.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I can explain this one, but I noticed that the result set in JMeter when searching for `@class` was returning `rid` instead of `rId` as it is in the response message being parsed. Changing over to `@rid` returns the values I was looking for.